# Is there any other way to retrieve the user and authorities data from database instead the sql function in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have implemented for my application the following SecurityConfig class, where I have two query functions to retrieve data from database:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value="org.webapp")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource restDataSource;

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(restDataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(getUserQuery())
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(getAuthoritiesQuery());
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/spring/erro-login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/image/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/spring/index").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/spring/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("senha")
                .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/spring/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/spring/index").permitAll();
    }

    private String getUserQuery() {
        return "SELECT login as username, senha as password "
                + "FROM usuario "
                + "WHERE login = ?";
    }

    private String getAuthoritiesQuery() {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT usuario.login as username, autorizacao.descricao as authority "
                + "FROM usuario, autorizacao_usuario, autorizacao "
                + "WHERE usuario.id = autorizacao_usuario.fk_usuario "
                + "AND autorizacao.id = autorizacao_usuario.fk_autorizacao "
                + "AND usuario.login = ? ";
    }

}
```

What are the other ways to retrieve this data from database? Is there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with a custom authentication provider, which can retrieve  credentials  using custom code. This is an example for an authentication provider based on JPA instead of JDBC:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    ....
}
```

and then to use it in the security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, I add this class to my project, but seems (by output in stacktrace), the application isn't using it in the login process. Is there any other place I should register this class, besides SecurityConfig.registerAuthentication?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get a user - Jhadesdev's answer is good, but an alternative is to implement UserServiceDetails - basically need to implement `loadUserByUsername()` method.

There is a tutorial on [it here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/custom-userdetailsservice-example-for-spring-3-security/)

You can also have a look at this example Spring 4 MVC project that implements the UserDetailsService:

[UserDetailsService implementation](https://github.com/robhinds/spring-four-template/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tmm/frm/security/UserDetailsServiceImpl.java)

[Security Configuration](https://github.com/robhinds/spring-four-template/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tmm/frm/configuration/SecurityConfig.java)

Comment: I have a class which implement UserDetailsService in my project, but when I try autowire it in SecurityConfig, I am getting an error. One question: the use of this method (with UserDetailsService) it's a replacement for the method which uses the custom AuthenticationProvider? Or I can have both classes registered in my SecurityConfig?

Comment: 1) what error do you get trying to autowire it? 2) Yes, you can use UserDetailsService alongside custom AuthenticationProvider 3) Do you need the custom Auth Provider for another reason? If you are just planning on doing username/password authentication, it can all be done just implementing UserDetailsService and leaving the rest to spring

Comment: the error I am getting is **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.webapp.service.UsuarioService field org.webapp.security.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32**. By the way, my curren SecurityClass.java is this: https://github.com/klebermo/webapp1/blob/master/src/org/webapp/security/SecurityConfig.java

Comment: just had a bit of a look at your project - are you enabling component scanning? Spring needs to know your UsarioService is a spring bean - as it is annotated @ Service, Spring needs to know to find/register it at startup - see this config file: https://github.com/robhinds/spring-four-template/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tmm/frm/configuration/ApplicationContextConfiguration.java - do you have @ ComponentScan anywhere? (you will see on that link that I am specifying packages that should be scanned at startup for annotated beans

Comment: Yes, I have this ComponentScan annotation in my classes SecurityConfig and WebAppConfig.

Comment: See this question/answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18369720/258813 you were not autowiring an interface, so need to enable that target class option to inject it.

Comment: And that is done in java config using: @ EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ, proxyTargetClass = true) anootation on your app config class - see: https://github.com/robhinds/spring-four-template/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tmm/frm/configuration/ApplicationContextConfiguration.java